# Reactive Forms with PrimeNG Controls not Firing

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-forms, primeng-calendar

I have HTML Page with PrimeNG Controls using reactive forms. PrimeNG controls are not triggered when a control is touched,dirty and invalid (IF a values is typed then cleared). However, if I just tab in then out without inputting any value then it works properly.

example:

**(See label and box boarders are "RED")**

[image]

Now if I select a value from location autocomplete dropdown thn delete it same for the phone type in a number then deleted , validations are no longer triggered

[image]

**HTML**

```
  <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3"
                                       [ngClass]="{
                                     'has-error':(ersaForm.get('phone').touched || ersaForm.get('phone').dirty ) &&
                                     !ersaForm.get('phone').valid
                                     }">

                                    <label for="phoneId" class="control-label">Phone</label><br />
                                    <p-inputMask mask="(999) 999-9999" formControlName="phone"   styleClass="form-control" [style]="{'width': '100%','height':'34px'}"  id="phoneId"  placeholder="Phone (required)"></p-inputMask>
                                    <span class="help-block"   *ngIf="(ersaForm.get('phone').touched || ersaForm.get('phone').dirty ) &&
                                     ersaForm.get('phone').errors">
                                        <span *ngIf="ersaForm.get('phone').errors.phonePBXCheck">
                                            Phone Number does not exist.
                                        </span>

                                    </span>

                                </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3"
                                       [ngClass]="{
                                     'has-error':(ersaForm.get('location').touched || ersaForm.get('location').dirty ) &&
                                     !ersaForm.get('location').valid
                                     }">
                                    <label for="locationId" class="control-label">Location</label>
                                    <p-autoComplete formControlName="location" id="locationId"  [suggestions]="iOffice" forceSelection="true" placeholder="Office (required)" inputStyleClass="form-control" (completeMethod)="searchOffice($event)"  [style]="{'width': '100%','display': 'inline-flex','height':'34px'}"  field="name" dataKey="id" [dropdown]="true"></p-autoComplete>

                                </div>
```

**TS**

```
this.ersaForm = this._fb.group({
            location: ['', Validators.required],
            phone: ['', [Validators.required, phoneCheck('')]],

        });

function phoneCheck(phone: string): ValidatorFn{


    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {

          some logic
        };
        return null;
    };
}
```

What is Missing !

****************************************UPDATE*********************************************

I took the custome validtor out

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3"
                                       [ngClass]="{
                                     'has-error':(ersaForm.get('phone').touched || ersaForm.get('phone').dirty ) &&
                                     !ersaForm.get('phone').valid
                                     }">

                                    <label for="phoneId" class="control-label">Phone</label><br />
                                    <p-inputMask mask="(999) 999-9999" formControlName="phone" (onBlur)="checkValidity();" unmask="true"  styleClass="form-control" [style]="{'width': '100%','height':'34px'}"  id="phoneId"  placeholder="Phone (required)"></p-inputMask>

                                </div>
```

**TS**

```
this.ersaForm = this._fb.group({
        phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        gatewayRole: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]),

        });

    checkValidity(): void {
            Object.keys(this.ersaForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
                console.log('inside validation');
                this.ersaForm.controls[key].markAsDirty;
            //    this.ersaForm.controls[key].
            });
        }
```

**F12 (input mask is showing ng-valid even if there is no input)**

```
<p-inputmask _ngcontent-c2="" formcontrolname="phone" id="phoneId" mask="(999) 999-9999" placeholder="Phone (required)" styleclass="form-control" unmask="true" ng-reflect-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-style-class="form-control" ng-reflect-placeholder="Phone (required)" ng-reflect-unmask="true" ng-reflect-mask="(999) 999-9999" ng-reflect-name="phone" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid">
<input pinputtext="" class="form-control ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget" ng-reflect-ng-class="form-control" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" type="text" placeholder="Phone (required)" style="width: 100%; height: 34px;"></p-inputmask>
<div _ngcontent-c2=""> This form is valid: false </div>
```

Comment: anyone can help!

Comment: can you create a stackbliz please

Answer (score 1):

Reactive form validation is  not firing with p-dropdown
--------------------------------------`enter code here`-------------------

### HTML

```
<p-dropdown [options]="lineNumbers" formControlName="Selectedline" [class.is-invalid]="Selectedline.dirty && Selectedline.touched" styleClass="form-control" placeholder="Select Line" [filter]="false" ></p-dropdown>
                          <div *ngIf="Selectedline.dirty && Selectedline.touched">
                                <small *ngIf="Selectedline.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Line Number is required</small>
                              </div>
                        </div>
```

### TS

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.createIOForm = this.fb.group({
      Selectedline: ["", Validators.required]


    });
  }

  Selectedline() {
    this.createIOForm.get("Selectedline");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try marking as dirty to trigger validation. 
If you look at the documentation for p-inputmask you will see that you can probably use (onBlur).
And for dropdown you can use (onChange).

Here is an example...

in .html file

```
<p-inputMask mask="(999) (onBlur)="checkValidity();" ...</p-inputMask>
...
<p-dropdown ... (onChange)="checkValidity(); "></p-dropdown>
```

In .ts file

```
 public checkValidity(): void {
        Object.keys(this.ersaForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
            this.formGroup.controls[key].markAsDirty();
        });
    }
```

Comment: i tried this solution and still behave the same. as soon as the control becomes dirty then input erased  , validation no longer trigger for the control where it's input has been erased

Comment: any ideas, ' this.formGroup.controls[key].markAsDirty();" is not working when I i did F12 o look at it the changes to the control once a control is touched the cls is set to "class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid"" but it should be invalid ...not sure why it is valid even the phone is empty

Comment: Check your logic in phoneCheck function

Comment: Try marking them as clean. Then Right after mark them as dirty.

Comment: updated my above code...i took out the custome validator and still not working

Comment: Have you tried the FormControl Object?
new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
    ]),

Comment: sill no luck :(

Comment: Can you add this to your code? And see if the formGroup is right.

<div>
    This form is valid: {{ersaForm.valid}}
</div>

Comment: I did, and it is not correct...always showing value "false" even if there is an input

Comment: have you tried 
this.ersaForm.get('phone').updateValueAndValidity();

Comment: updated my code (see F12) using the developer tool the iput mask is set as "ng-valid" even if there is no value! it only shows ng-invalid if nothing has been entered into the control. so if i type 999999999 the earse my input , input mask will show as ng-valid

Comment: That is very strange. I honestly don't know what your issue is. I would suggest deleting everything and start with a working bare bones dynamic form. Then add on from that point on. Good Luck..

Comment: but thing is, for "no primeNG form" which I have such as input box validations is working properly...this happens only with primeNG Controls....in this page I have primeNG and none PrimeNG controls..the non primeNG controls are working properly

Comment: If you want to go away from the prime ng mask just use a regex validator on an input field. It will be able to handle an empty string or allow the user to enter the number exactly how you want them to. That's what I would use over the input mask.